# Entity Framework and One to Many Relationships Code First

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have been having trouble understanding what I would think is a simple relationship model.  I have a `CloudFile` object that represents a file on a CDN.  I have two other objects, `Creative` and `Merchant`, that relate to the `CloudFile`.

**My CloudFile Class**

```
public class CloudFile
{
    [Key]
    public int CloudFileId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string OriginalFileName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(5)]
    public string FileExt { get; set; }

    public int Height { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public long SizeInBytes { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    public CloudFile()
    {
        this.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

**My Creative Class**

```
public class Creative
{
    [Key]
    public int CreativeId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int OfferId { get; set; }
    public virtual Offer Offer { get; set; }

    public virtual CloudFile CloudFile { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Alt { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    public Creative()
    {
        this.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
        this.CloudFile = new CloudFile();
    }
}
```

**My Merchant Class**

```
public class Merchant
{
    #region Keys
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "Merchant ID")]
    public int MerchantId { get; set; }
    #endregion

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Merchant Name")]
    [StringLength(256)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual CloudFile CloudFile { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Offer> Offers { get; set; }
    public ICollection<MerchantLocation> Locations { get; set; }

    public Merchant()
    {
        this.Offers = new List<Offer>();
        this.Locations = new List<MerchantLocation>();
    }
```

I am not sure how to associate and save these objects properly in the database. I have tried adding a new CloudFile object to Merchant.CloudFile and then running the following:

```
    ......
    merchant.CloudFile = new CloudFile() {...set properties here...};
    MerchantDB.Modify(merchant);
    ......

    public static bool Modify(Merchant merchant)
    {
        using (AppDbContext db = new AppDbContext())
        {
            db.Entry(merchant).State = EntityState.Modified;

            //Return true if only 1 record was modified.  If not, return false.
            return (db.SaveChanges() == 1);
        }
    }
```

But it does not save the CloudFile and associate it with Merchant.  I am able to directly save the CloudFile to the CloudFile table but there is still no association.

Thanks for you assistance in advance!

Answer (score 0):

That is because you had not mentioned two way relationship , i.e. no navigation property from your cloudtfile to creative and merchant class , try adding below lines to your cloudfile model

```
public Creative creativeObj { get; set; }
public Merchant merchantObj { get; set; }
```

also change

```
db.Entry(merchant).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

to

```
db.Entry(cloudfile).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Comment: So if I have other objects that will need a reference to CloudFile I will need to add them to the CloudFile class also?  Isnt that backwards?

Comment: FrankO: Thumb rule which i follow is to always mention two way relation, and if you wanted to navigate from cloudfile to merchant then this has to be there, infact if it is one to one relation you can see in your db it must have created some table name CloudFileMerchant

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  I was just trying to create a single table called CloudFiles that would hold any Merchant, Creative or any other business entity file that is located in the cloud CDN.  Is this not the right approach?

Comment: I guess i did not get you properly , but from EF perspective things are very simple if you follow conventions, if you wanted to navigate to merchant or creative entity from cloudfile you need to have a navigation property in you cloudfile model, so if cloudfile is you entities which is exposed to outside world and given a cloudfile id you are supposed to load information related to merchant then its better to have merchant associated with cloudfile. Please dont forgot to mark it as answer if it had answered your question :)

Comment: Thanks Anshul.  Would you have an example of what you mean "so if cloudfile is you entities which is exposed to outside world and given a cloudfile id you are supposed to load information related to merchant then its better to have merchant associated with cloudfile."?

Comment: Maybe I approach it differently.  Like adding the CloudFile to the database, storing its ID with the Merchant or Creative and then retrieving the CloudFile using the ID when I need it?